How far away is a number from being a power?
Suppose $n\in \mathbb N$ is given, now I would like to know how "far" $n$ is, from being a non-trivial power of some other natural number i.e. what can we say about:
$\min\{|n-m^x|: m,x\in \mathbb N_{\ge 2}\} =: a$
I asked myself this question recently while working on something else related to this. Initially my thought was that the above minimum maybe becomes arbitrarily large for larger $n$, but I'm not so sure anymore after plotting $\{ m^x: m,x\in \mathbb N_{\ge 2}\}$. Maybe an initial approach of doing this would be to count non-trivial powers in a given interval by some combinatorial argument, and then say something about how they are distributed, but I don't have a clue really.
Hopefully someone else also finds this interesting and can help me out here, thanks in advance for any suggestions!
I have attached an image of how non-trivial powers (highlighted in red) are distributed in the interval $[1,1000]$

EDIT: To get the ball rolling, I came up with the following vanilla bound on $a$:
notice $n\in [\lfloor n^{1/2}\rfloor ^2,\lceil n^{1/2} \rceil^2]$.
therefore
$a \le \frac{\lceil n^{1/2} \rceil^2 - \lfloor n^{1/2}\rfloor ^2}{2} = \lfloor n^{1/2}\rfloor + \frac{1}{2}$;
in particular because $a$ is an integer $a \le \lfloor n^{1/2}\rfloor$.

I mean, if you have a decent bound on the minimum as above in terms of the prime divisors of $n$ or something along those lines, that would also be interesting to me of course @user25406

The sequence A053289 and the references there may be of interest.

Note that for a given $n$, the largest $x$ is $\approx\log_2(n)$

Thank you for the reference, very interesting @Jair Taylor

The distance from $n$ to the nearest $k$th power of an integer is exactly $\min\{ n-\lfloor m^{1/k}\rfloor^k,\lceil m^{1/k}\rceil^k - n \}$. Therefore if $n\le2^B$, the distance from $n$ to the nearest perfect power is exactly
$$
\min\bigl\{ \min\{ n-\lfloor m^{1/2}\rfloor^2,\lceil m^{1/2}\rceil^2 - n, \ldots, \min\{ n-\lfloor m^{1/B}\rfloor^B,\lceil m^{1/B}\rceil^B - n \} \} \bigr\}.
$$
(One can consider only prime exponents, for that matter.)
This is actually a continuous function of the real number $n$, for that matter; its graph is shown below.

I'm pretty sure that it's easy to show that this function is at least $\lfloor n^{1/2}\rfloor$ infinitely often, since most midpoints-between-consecutive-squares won't be that close to other perfect powers.

I think one can make your last sentence into a rigorous statement as follows. The proportion of perfect powers between say $n$ and $2n$ that are squares goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity. In other words, for almost all numbers the nearest perfect power is either $\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor$ or $\lceil n^{1/2} \rceil$.

Awesome graphic, thank you! @Greg Martin

You can trivially calculate the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc root of n, rounded to the nearest integer. And you don't need k-th roots where k is composite, saving quite a lot of work. For small n, say n ≤ 10^10, this should be plenty fast. So assume n is large.
It is most likely that the 2nd root leads to the solution. So you need to calculate that. If n is 100 digits then the square root is 50 digits, and the error will be about 50 digits. Next you could calculate the 3rd root which would be 33 digits. To beat the 2nd root the result must be very close to an integer. You can find this while calculating the third root with less than 100 digits precision. And once you look at the 7th root of a 100 digit number, calculating that root with ordinary floating-point arithmetic will be good enough. For say the 100th or higher root of a 100 digit number, you can check whether any power of 10, 9, 8 etc is close to n.
